# C++ setting array values in a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am having trouble with what seems like a very simple concept. I have a class like such:

```
class Projectile
{
public:
    int count;
    int projectiles[1][3];

    Projectile();
    void newProjectile();

};

Projectile::Projectile()
{
    count = 0;
}

void Projectile::newProjectile()
{
    projectiles[0][0] = { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

I am trying to set the values inside the `projectiles` array, and I must be doing this incorrectly. How can I go about dynamically adding a set of values into this property?

Comment: If there is just 1 row, what is the point of having a 2 dimensional array ?

Comment: The idea will be to add additional rows later. I just need to set a size initially.. i think.

Comment: Then `vector<vector<int>>` is what you want, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 projectiles[0][0] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

This isn't correct. Initializer lists can only given at the point of declaration. You have to **assign** values independently to each location of the array elements. `std::vector<std::vector> twoDimArray;` is what you want.

```
struct foo{

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > twoDimArray;
    void create(int size){

        std::vector<int> oneDimArray(size);
        // vector as of now can just accommodate size number of elements. They aren't
        // assigned any values yet.


        twoDimArray.push_back(oneDimArray); // Copy it to the twoDimArray

        // Now if you wish to increase the size of each row, just push_back element to 
        //  that row. 
        twoDimArray[0].push_back(8);
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to set this up :) ? it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Headspin - See the update. But if you are new to std::vector, first play with a vector that can hold primitive types like `int`. Then it is much easier to understand of vector holding another vector.

Comment: This is a great example. Just one last question. How would I store this as a property in my class?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly do you meant by "store this as a property" ?

Comment: As in, how would I declare it as a public variable accessible to the rest of the class?

Comment: `struct` is no different from `class`, except that it's members are `public` by default. Declare the variable as `private` and all it's members should be able to access it.

Comment: Ha you bet! I have but one last question if you wouldnt mind. How do I assign values to the pair? `std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > pjtls;` Would I do something like `pjtls[0](1,2)` I am positive this is wrong but hopefully you understand the question!

Comment: `pair` is entirely a different data structure. To assign to it you need to use `.first`,`.second`. `pjtls.push_back( std::pair<int.int> ); pjtls[0].first = 10; pjtls[0].second = 20;`

Comment: like such? `pjtls[0].first(1)` and `pjtls[0].first(2)`

Comment: Great! Thanks so much! I appreciate your patience ha. I'm just trying to jump right into this stuff.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3478/discussion-between-headspin-and-mahesh)

Answer (score 3):

`projectiles[0][0]` refers to a specific location in a two-dimensional array, its type is `int`

If you want to dynamically add items, then you can use `std::vector<int>` (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/))

Comment: Please look at at link I gave. If it still doesn't help, I'll see what I can do... :-)

Comment: Ah I see. Never worked with these. It is possible to store a vector as a value in a vector? Like a 2 dim vector? What i am trying to achieve is a 2 dimensional array like structure which holds an x and y coordinate for each member of the array. Is this possible with vectors?

Comment: Yes (Mahesh pointed this out in his answer). Although there might be better alternatives, such as `std::vector< std::pair<int, int> >` if you want to store x, y coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
void Projectile::newProjectile()
{
    projectiles[0][0] = 1;
    projectiles[0][1]=2;
    projectiles[0][2]=3;

}
```